# How can we use protractor in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, protractor

Can we write protractor test/scripts in eclipse. Enabling syntax highlighting , intellisense etc. for Javascript in Eclipse.

Comment: Any update on this , can someone reply ??

Comment: Please check out [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). However to answer your question, yes you can use it. [Check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203062/how-to-run-protractor-test-case-using-ide/32205609#32205609)

Comment: Agreed made it short .. But can you please let me know how do we need make it works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use protractor plugin in eclipse.

1. Go to help-->Marketplace
2. Search for **tern.java**
3. Install **Tern Eclipse IDE**
4. and accept the licence.

**Now create a project in eclipse**

1. Right click on project,
2. Mouse hover to configure and
3. Click on **convert to tern project**
4. Properties window pop-up>> goto Modules
5. you will be able to see Protractor,
6. Select the check box and click on the Protractor and
7. Also check the dependencies as well.

**Now you are ready to write scripts using protractor.**

Comment: Wow.. Thankyouuu somuch Nick .. Appreciate it !!

Comment: You can read https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Protractor-support. Please note this support is only for completion, validation, hyperlink but not to execute tests.

Comment: @Angelo do you have any idea on how to execute the test in eclipse? how to start protractor server in eclipse

Comment: @Nick, I don't know today, but when I will find time, I would like to support it with AngularJS Eclipse which is based on tern.java. Please create an issues at https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues by describing how to it should work (I have never used Protractor)

Comment: @Nick please install AngularJS Eclipse 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT which provide Run/Debug support for Protractor https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor

Comment: Hi, I followed your instruction but found out that tern is outdated. wild web developer is new but I there is no clear info on how to use it for protractor

Answer (score 0):

Adding more content to Nick's answer , after the step  3. Click on convert to tern project you will ask to select the modules, leave the one's that
automatically selected and in addition select

Angular JS
Browser
Browser extention
Protractor
Jasmine.

Then in project level write click and create a new file  samfirstspec.js
Copy https://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial the content in Step 0 - write a test

```
    // samfirstspec.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
  });
});
```

Next step is creating a  configuration file.In project level write click and create a new file 
 Copy the following into myconfig.js

```
 // conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['samfirstspec.js']
}
```

This configuration tells Protractor where your test files (specs) are, 
and where to talk to your Selenium Server (seleniumAddress). It specifies that we will be using Jasmine for the test framework. 
It will use the defaults for all other configuration. Chrome is the default browser.

The next step is running the script so go to project source code location via cmd

F:\Learning\Repositories\protractor-sam-test-scripts\EclipsePro

In cmd type

protractor myconfig.js

refer this too - https://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial