# how to Configure protractor using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, protractor

When i have followed steps given on [How can we use protractor in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200154/how-can-we-use-protractor-in-eclipse)
i did not get any option to run as protractor in eclipse during run. please help me out

Comment: I don't know, what you think in here.  Protractor is indepent from Eclipse or any IDE. Because Protractor is used in node projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find out the way to configure eclipse to run protractor test cases. it is given in below link
https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor

Answer (score 4):

I was able to configure protractor tests in eclipse and below are the steps which I performed including one error that I resolved with some tweaks.

1. Open Eclipse market place > Search for AngularJS Eclipse > Install
   AngularJS Eclipse 1.X.X
2. Create Java Script Project
3. Add conf.js and example-spec.js in the java script project (both JS
   are preloaded inside example folder of protractor directory)
4. Now from command prompt navigate inside this java script directory
   and execute command :- npm install protractor (this command will
   load node_modules folder inside your project directory)
5. Convert Java Script Project to Tern Project (Right click on project

   > Configure > Convert to Tern Project)
6. A new modal window will appear > Select Jasmine & Protractor check
   box > Apply
7. Now go to Run configuration of your project (Right click on your
   project > Run > Run configuration)
8. You would see protractor(in left pane)> Add a new configuration of
   Protractor > Add path of conf.js (Main tab)> Add path of Working
   Directory (Main tab)
9. From the second sub tab which says protractor > Add path of cli.js
   (this must be with in protractor folder > built > cli.js)
10. Select apply and run
11. I came across below error

E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.

12. This error I resolved after pasting webdriver-manager folder from
    AppData > npm > Node_modules > Protractor > Webdriver-manager to
    WorkingDirector > Node_modules > protractor > webdriver-manager

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the above but nothing seem to work as my eclipse is the latest one. Latest eclipse has new plugins. AngularJS plugin is deprecated and renamed as Wild Web Developer and there is one more plugin called "Nodeclipse.github.io" which contains Tern project. Here is a link below which gives the detailed installation and configuration of the protractor with the latest eclipse and other plugins.

http://selftechy.com/2019/12/08/setting-up-protractor-with-latest-eclipse-windows-plugins-settings