# Protractor with Eclipse: Protractor option is missing on Run Configuration popup

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

Protractor with Eclipse: Protractor option is missing on Run Configuration popup.

I followed the http://www.protractortest.org/#/ and [how to Configure protractor using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344636/how-to-configure-protractor-using-eclipse) (followed 2 Answer steps), butt still Protractor option is hidden.

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Just install **Angularjs Eclipse** from Eclipse marketplace

-that's it, now it will display in your Run Configuration.