# E/configParser - Error message: configuration file cli.js did not export a config object

Tags: angularjs, node.js, eclipse, npm, protractor

I am new to protractor, and I successfully setup the protractor in eclipse.I followed this https://www.protractortest.org/#/ link, where conf.js contains:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

and spec.js contains:

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

code as mentioned on the link. But when I execute the conf.js it shows me below error in eclipse's console.

```
[10:31:25] E/configParser - Error code: 105

[10:31:25] E/configParser - Error message: configuration file D:\Selenium_Workspace\ProtractorJavaScriptProject5\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js did not export a config object

[10:31:25] E/configParser - Error: configuration file D:\Selenium_Workspace\ProtractorJavaScriptProject5\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js did not export a config object   

at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (D:\Selenium_Workspace\ProtractorJavaScriptProject5\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:141:19)
at Object.initFn [as init] (D:\Selenium_Workspace\ProtractorJavaScriptProject5\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js:93:22)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Selenium_Workspace\ProtractorJavaScriptProject5\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js:225:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Since the code at the link you've provided is not so big, could you please EDIT your question and include it? That link may get broken someday.

Comment: Please show the cmd how you used to execute the `conf.js`, I think you used wrong command.

Comment: @yong I am not executing it through cmd,I am executing it through eclipse by right clicking on conf.js-> Run As-> Run Configuration-> Select Protractor from Left panel-> select Protractor tab ->import cli.js file protractor lib field-> browse node.js-> Click on Apply -> then Click on Run button.

Comment: Can you give url you used to integrate protractor into eclipse, so that i can try on my local to debug your problem.

Comment: @yong, I followed "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344636/how-to-configure-protractor-using-eclipse" (Answer  by vdrulerz) and "protractortest.org/#/"; links.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my run configuration which worked on my eclipse.

**1) Main Tab**  `test` is my project folder

[image]

**2) Protractor Tab**
[image]

I installed `Angularjs Eclipse 1.2` which fail to enable me to choose Nodejs installed by my self, I have to use the embed Nodejs in `Angularjs Eclipse 1.2`,  but this one is lower version can't satisfy my Protractor, thus I copy my high version node.exe into the embed Nodejs install folder to overwrite the lower node.exe. After that all things worked as expected well

Some Google search said `Angularjs Eclipse 1.3` can fix the `can't choose self installed Nodejs`, but I have no luck to get it installed on my Eclipse java Luna and Eclipse jee Luna.

Comment: Thanx a lot @yong, i am so happy, now its working fine. I was doing mistake in Main tab.