# Protractor eclipse - ReferenceError: describe is not defined

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, protractor

I'm new to protractor, trying to run simple test via eclipse, but for some reason I'm getting this below error.

```
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ram\pworkspace\test\test.js:4:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
```

There is no `cli.js` under `protractor/lib/cli.js` but it exists in  `/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js`, I have given this path under protractor client file.

Can anybody let me know to resolve this issue?

Comment: Show what is inside `C:\Users\ram\pworkspace\test\test.js` (edit the question and post it there). Thanks.

Comment: [Set Up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200154/how-can-we-use-protractor-in-eclipse) Try this and let me know

Comment: Cool it's working now, missed conf.js , iam trying to use cucumber along with protractor , is there any cucumber-protractor plugin for eclipse?